# Why return this.each(function()) in jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Some of the tutorials and examples I have seen for developing jQuery plugins tend to return

```
this.each(function () {
    //Plugin code here
});
```

at the end of the function that instantiates the plugin but I have yet to see any reasoning behind it, it just seems to be a standard that everyone follows.  Can anyone enlighten me as to the reasoning behind this practice?

Edit: For clarification my question was not about why to return this, but rather why the plugin should return this.each.

Comment: That IS strange.  It seems like just returning `this` would be a far better idea..

Comment: @Walt W - I agree.  I understand why we would return this, because that keeps with the idea of the fluent interface.  But the part that I dont understand is the each call.

Comment: Just to clarify, are the functions blank as you wrote them?  Or is there code in there?

Comment: @Walt w - No the functions are not blank, I should have clarified.  I will update my code example.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

When you filter elements with a selector (`$('.myclass')`), it can match more than only one element.
With `each`, you iterate over **all matched elements** and your code is applied to all of them.

Comment: Of course!  Thanks, I guess I just took that for granted everytime I have used plugins previously.

Comment: While this is absolutely true, the actual reason to `return` it is to allow chaining...

Comment: @Mef: Well I thought this is clear and it is more about why using `each`.

Comment: If you have code you want to run one time after that .each() loop, could you just 'return this' after the loop & run-last code?

Answer (score 24):

jQuery supports "chainable methods", which means that *most* jQuery functions should return `this`.  [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) returns `this`, and if you want `$('selector').yourPlugin().css(...)` to work, you should `return this`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The reason you return is to allow chainability.

Answer (score 11):

Let me show you two "equivalent" pieces of code that could clarify your question:

**With jQuery "each" function:**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mangle = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).append(' - ' + $(this).data('x'));
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Without jQuery "each" function:**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mangle = function(options) {
        var objs = this;
        for (var i=0; i<objs.length; i++) {
            var obj = objs[i];
            $(obj).append(' - ' + $(obj).data('x'));
        };
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So, basically, `each` function is used to apply some code to all elements contained in `this` object (*as `this` usually refers to a group of elements returned by a jQuery selector*) and return the reference to `this` (*as `each` function always returns that reference -to allow chaining calls-*)

**As a side note**:  The second approach (*-`for` loop-*) is faster (notably on old browsers) than former one (*-`each` function-*).

Answer (score 7):

When you write a plugin you are extending the jQuery object, and because the jQuery object is a sequence you return `this.each(function () { });` so that your plugin is executed for each item of the sequence.

Comment: but your are actually just returning "one" "this" right? the each part is separate, isn´t it?

Comment: @Marcel: yes, in fact you can call `each` and then return `this`, as two separate statements. It works because `each` also returns `this`.

Answer (score 4):

In short it allows you to take advantage of chaining, since it returns everything that has been done till now so the next `.anyMethod()` can act upon the changed/modified elements.

Additionally, take a look at these links they will give you a lot of information on jQuery plugin development.

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-plugin-development-10-tutorials-to-get-started/ 
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern  
http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery_plugin

And here you have a nice web based app that helps you jump start your jQuery plugins. 
http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/