# Animate a div when focus an input

Tags: jquery

I need to animate a div when focus an input. I tried this but is not working.

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        marginLeft: "0"
    }, 500);
});
```

The initial position is  margin-left: -500px. The jQuery is installed correctly. When I try to do the same but with a div instead of a input It works.

```
$(".a_div").click(function() {
$("div").animate({
    marginLeft: "0"
}, 500);
});
```

But I changed to an input and no longer works.

Comment: `I tried this but is not working.` what do you mean by not working can you create a snippet for demo?

Comment: What is the `<div>`'s value for `margin-left` before the animation? Also, is jQuery installed correctly?

Comment: The initial position is  margin-left: -500px. And yes, jQuery is installed correctly. When I try to do the same but with a div instead of a input It works. 

$("input").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        marginLeft: "0"
    }, 500);
});

But I changed to an input and no longer works.

Comment: Here is fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Harin/mnjdn3cx/1/ . Working fine.

Comment: check out this it works on focus in : https://jsfiddle.net/3338cej0/

Comment: Look a example event input http://stackoverflow.com/a/43665925/2777092