# tipr.js understanding the usage of the each function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hover

Hey guys i was trying to cusomize the Jquery plugin Tipr.js and came across a small hurdle , basically i  was playing around with the source code . and came across the following :

```
 return this.each(function() {
```

if the above line on line 21 is removed and the preceding closing brackets are removed from line 46 .

see the source code to see what i am saying.

[Source code](https://github.com/gautamz07/Tipr/blob/master/tipr/tipr.js)

the plugin still works fine . i mean i does what it suppose to . however on running more tests i came to know that removing the each function from the plugin affects the chanability of the plugin, for eg. now with the each removed i can't do this :

```
$('#xyz').tipr().addClass('xyz');
```

now i understand the usage of the each function , but somehow in the context of this pluggin , i don't understand WHY the each function affects changeability .

[How to create a basic plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) : this documentation helped me out a bit , but i stil could't totally understand.

it would be really fantastic of somebody could explain what important role the each function is playing here .

thanks.

Tenali

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678185/why-return-this-eachfunction-in-jquery-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link `@Learner` provided is good, however it is old and the "accepted" answer there is not the "correct" answer.

In your specific example, the original code looks like:

```
return this.each(function() {
    ...
});
```

which, for a basic `each` is actually just a shorter version of this:

```
this.each(function() {
    ...
});
return this;
```

so you can now clearly see that by removing that entire line, you are not returning anything from the function.

It is not the lack of the `each` that is the problem, and you *could* remove that `each` if you only want to attach to a single element e.g.

```
return this;
```

it is the lack of *any return value* that stops the ability to chain your jQuery extension.

Comment: new to Jquery ! so stil learning new things ! perfectly answered though ! Thanks ! .